# Difference between "mongo" and "mongod"?

Tags: mongodb

I've installed MongoDB and I've found some unlogical things and I hope someone will answer me:

1. When I execute "mongo" I get logged into shell
2. When I execute "mongodb" I get the following errors:

   ```
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7221 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=debian
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
    4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.302+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.303+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.303+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.303+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.325+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.325+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.325+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
    2016-06-23T22:58:39.325+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
   ```

What is the difference between two terminal commands: mongo as a first, and mongodb as a second?

MongoDB is great because my project is schema-less but it's always  a horrible experience to configure it, create roles, authorization etc.

Thanks.

Comment: mongod is for database and mongo is for mongo command line

Answer (score 4):

- mongod is the server, to which requests to connect database are passed for example.
- In above error, it shows that port address 27017 is in use. It means your   mongod is already runnning. You just need to run command 'mongo' to access the Mongodb shell.
- There is another possibility that some other process is running on port 27017
- `netstat -n | grep 27017` to check if process is running and `kill -9 $(lsof -ti:27017)'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I execute "mongodb" there are lots of errors. Should I worry about that, because I can login with "mongo". 

Now it returns `** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 7982 processes, 65536 files. Number of processes should be at least 32768 : 0.5 times number of files.˙ `Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'` `Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
` `waiting for connections on port 27017`

Answer (score 3):

To use any database service, you have to start the database Server and same is the case with mongodb, the command `mongod` is used to start the MongoDB Server on your local machine or server.

*In your question you have asked for the command `mongodb` that's not correct you need to run command `mongod`, 'b' is not the part of this command.*

- When you run the `mongod`, it starts your mongodb server on default
  port 27017.
- Then you open another terminal and use the command `mongo` to enter
  into the mongo shell and perform your database operations.

> The difference between the both commands is that `mongod` starts the
>   mongodb server and `mongo` allows you to enter into mongo shell to
>   perform further database operations.

Also, when you install mongodb, you have an option to install it as a *service*. Installing mongodb as a service starts the mongodb server in background when you boot your system.